# SQL subselect filtering based on multiple sub-rows

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

I have two tables, and want to extract certain columns from the first, based on 'child' data from the second.

- I'm using SQL Anywhere 12

---

Table 1)
Lets call it **Projects**

```
proj_id | Name  
--------+---------        
10      | Proj_1
20      | Proj_2
30      | Proj_3
40      | Proj_4
```

---

Table 2)
Lets call this one **tasks**

```
proj_id | task_id | Status
--------+---------+-----------
10      | 1       | Ready
10      | 2       | Cancelled
10      | 3       | Ready
20      | 1       | Complete
20      | 2       | Ready
30      | 1       | Ready
30      | 2       | Not Ready
30      | 3       | Complete
40      | 1       | Ready
40      | 2       | Ready
```

---

Want I want to do is find out which **'projects'** have **'tasks'** that are **'ready'**.

The tricky part here is that it is OK if other **tasks** are **Complete**, but its not OK if they are anything other than **complete** or **ready**

So in other words the output should look like this:

```
Name   | Status
-------+--------
Proj_2 | Ready
Proj_4 | Ready
```

What I **don't** want in the result set is to see **Proj_1** (a task was **cancelled**) or **Proj_3** (a task is **not ready**)

I'm not posting any SQL, because I'm not sure if this is even possible....

Normally I would do something like this in C++ in 2 multiple statements, but in this case I need it in a single statement, as I need to pass the data to a third party printing program.

Comment: What I forgot to mention is that this statement actually has 6 tables to join (with future expansion possible) and the statement itself will be stored in the DB, which has a 2000 character limit....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this type of query.  I like to use aggregation with a `having` clause, because it is quite flexible and all the logic goes in the `having` clause:

```
select t.proj_id
from tasks t
group by t.proj_id
having sum(case when status = 'ready' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when status not in ('complete, 'ready') then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts the number of tasks that have a particular condition.  The first counts the number of ready tasks, and the `> 0` says there is at least one.  The second counts the number of non-ready, non-complete counts.  The `= 0` says there are none.

Comment: This is what I need thank you! I can keep it tidy even if (when) I need to add to the statement later.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of using having, too close to the problem I guess.

Answer (score 0):

`NOT EXISTS` solution, i.e. return a project if it has a ready task, and no task other than ready and complete:

```
select p.*
from Projects p
  join tasks t on p.proj_id = t.proj_id
where t.Status = 'ready'
  and not exists (select * from tasks t2
                  where t2.proj_id = t.proj_id
                    and t2.Status NOT IN ('ready', 'Complete'))
```

Comment: max = min doesn't allow for 'Complete' which is allowed, maybe: `min(status) in ('Complete','Ready')`

Comment: @Used_By_Already, sorry, didn't read carefully enough... Now corrected.

Comment: This is very similar to what I initially tried to do, but unfortunately (there are 6 tables to join) the statement became very messy. Thanks for your answer.